# Create list from 2D list based on conditions

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have a 2D Array in Python that is set up like

```
MY_ARRAY = [
    ['URL1', "ABC"],
    ['URL2'],
    ['URL3'],
    ['URL4', "ABC"]
]
```

I want to make an array of first element of each array only if the 2nd parameter is "ABC". So the result of the above example would be `['URL1', 'URL4']`

I tried to do `[x[0] for x in MY_ARRAY if x[1] == 'ABC']` but this returns `IndexError: list index out of range`. I think this is because sometimes `x[1]` is nonexistant.

I am looking for this to be a simple one-liner.

Comment: `[x[0] for x in MY_ARRAY if 1 < len(x) and x[1] == 'ABC']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply add a length check to the filtering criteria first. This works because Python short-circuits boolean expressions.

```
[ele[0] for ele in MY_ARRAY if len(ele) > 1 and ele[1] == 'ABC']
```

Also note that the proper terminology here is a list of lists, not an array.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try doing this:

```
if len(x) > 1:
    if x[1] == 'ABC':
        #do something here
```

This is a work around, but you can try it on one-liner code using:

```
if len(x) > 1 and x[1] == "ABC"
```

Cheers!

Comment: `&&` should be `and` - this is Python remember :)

Comment: @Mitch oh right I'm sorry I was using C++ and Python at the same time, I'm confuse some times, thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
[x[0] for x in MY_ARRAY if len(x) > 1 and x[1] == 'ABC']
```

It is happening because you have two list are having only one item and you are trying to access second item from that list

Answer (score 1):

First, let me tell you are on the right track, when `x[1]` doesn't exist you get the error

But, it's a bad habit to insist on doing things as a one-liner if it complicates matters.

Having said that, here's a one-liner that does that:

```
NEW_ARRAY = [x[0] for x in MY_ARRAY if len(x)>1 and x[1]=='ABC']
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution that works for my usage.

```
[x[0] for x in MY_ARRAY if x[-1] == 'ABC']
```

`x[-1]` will always exist since thats the last element in the array/list.

Comment: This doesn't meet your own constraints provided in the question, though. What if one of the nested lists is `['Foo', 'Bar', 'ABC']`, or `['ABC']`?

Comment: I don't think this is better than the other answers. Sure it might work for your use case, but if there were additional constraints like "what Mitch said will never happen" that would've led to better answers, you should've mentioned them.

Comment: The following checks the _second_ item of each sublist: `[x[0] for x in MY_ARRAY if x[1:] and x[1] == 'ABC']` and would handle the two cases @Mitch mentions.

Comment: @martineau Huh that one didn't occur to me, interesting. Although arguably less understandable, and if our data had some longer sublists it could get noticeably slow.